# unable to send JSON from HTML code

Tags: jquery, playframework

I want to send JSON to Play server from HTML page. The HTML takes user details and should 'post' the details to play server using JSON format. I am using JQuery. On using debugger, I notice that the serialize function returns empty data and response from play server is 400 bad request because the data isn't in 'text/json or application/json body'

UPDATE - The problem with serialise returning empty was that I hadn't specified 'name' attribute for input elements. Now serialize doesn't return empty string but the encoding is still not in JSON. Thus I continue to get 400 response.

Update - I am able to send JSON now but the server code is behaving in strange way. Using debugger, I can see that the server is resposding Ok but I get an error page

```
Bad request
For request 'POST /newreg' [Expecting text/json or application/json body]
```

HTML Code

```
@(form:Form[User2])

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:font-variant="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>HTML Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")">

    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css"-->
    <style type="text/css">

        html, body {
          height:100%;
          margin:0;padding:0
        }

        .center-form {
          width:100%;
          margin:auto;
          position:relative;
          top:50%;
          transform: translateY(-50%)
}


</style>

    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container center-form" >

    <!-- for medium and large screens,
    First row of Bootstrap grid contains logo. Total 3 columns (12/4). Logo in middle column-->

    <div class="row" >
        <!--empty column-->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" ></div>

        <!--logo column-->

        <!--empty column-->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>

    <!-- for medium and large screens,
    Second row of Bootstrap grid contains the form for username and password. Total 3 columns (12/4). -->
        <div class="row" >
            <!--empty column-->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>

            <!--form-->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">

            <form id="registration-form" action="/newreg" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name" name="first-name" value="@form("name").value" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name" name="last-name" value="@form("name").value" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="@form("email").value" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm-password" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="street-name">Street Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street-name" name="street-name" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="country">Country</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country" required>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!--empty column-->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myScripts.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller - Either print name or return bad request

```
def registrationRequest = Action (parse.json){ request =>
    (request.body \ "first-name").asOpt[String].map {name =>
/* In debugger, I can see that this code gets hit but I still get an error page!*/
      Ok("hello" + name)
    }.getOrElse{
      BadRequest("bad request")
    }
  }
```

myScripts.js

```
function objectifyForm(formArray) {//serialize data function

  returnArray = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++){
    returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
  }
  return returnArray;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // click on form submit
    $('#registration-form').on('submit',function(e){
    var details = JSON.stringify(objectifyForm($(this).serializeArray()));
    console.log(details)
        // send ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: '/newreg', // url where to submit the request
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            datatype : "json", // data type
/* this doesn't work*/
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                /*this does STRANGE!!!*/
                contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : details,
            success : function(result) {
                // you can see the result from the console
                // tab of the developer tools
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `dataType : 'json'` property to the `ajax` jQuery call.

Comment: I have added the jquery code I copied from other questions in StackOverflow. A strange behaviour I notice is that `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` doesnt work but `contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8"` does. Please see the question again about a new weird behavior I am facing now!

Comment: This is not a forum, it's much better to close the question and open a new one if you resolve the one issue and got another, just like now. The reason is - clarity, I hardly imagine that someone understands the problem on this issue now. I just not believe that you got an error if you have success "ok" string. Are there some errors in the log ? can you reproduce it on the simple example?  All of this better to describe in the new question.

Comment: your comment is valid. I have opened another question for new problem (and have found a solution as well). - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637029/i-am-sending-ok-but-the-browser-is-showing-bad-request/42638227#42638227